# The scope query parameter is missing from the authorization request (Intuit Developer Oauth2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to integrate my Ruby on Rails app to Quickbooks Online but having trouble during oauth2.0 process. I'm geting the error;`"The scope query parameter is missing from the authorization request."` from this url; `https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/connect/oauth2/error?error_code=MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER_SCOPE`. But I know my scope value is not missing and correct, it didn't give any error before using the same code that I used in my testing app. The code block I use for authentication is located below;
This code works under a helper called: `sessions_helper.rb`

```py
def get_quickbooks_login_url
  client_id = "MY_ID_KEY"
  client_secret = "MY_SECRET"
  oauth_params = {
     site: "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
     authorize_url: "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
     token_url: "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
  }
  oauth2_client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, oauth_params)
  redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth_tokens/new?service=quickbooks'
  grant_url = oauth2_client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri, response_type: "code", state: SecureRandom.hex(12), scope: "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting")
end
```

Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was using the `"Connect to Quickbooks"` button from  [minimulcasts](https://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html) tutorial. In my test application it didn't cause any trouble but in my real app it crashed the oAuth process. I think it's because of the javascript files in the button. The button was this;

```py
<div>
  <ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
  <script>
      intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '/path/to/blue-dot', grantUrl: '<%= get_quickbooks_login_url %>'});
  </script>
</div>
```

I changed this button simply with this;

```
<a href="<%= get_quickbooks_login_url %>" role="button" id="connect-button" class="btn btn-info">Connect to Quickbooks</a>
```

And my problem is solved. But now I'm getting `wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)` error which I think caused by `SimpleCommand`. Wish me luck.